# safety of keyword as function name

Tags: dart

*import* is a keword, yet the following works fine:

```
import 'dart:io';

void main() {
  import() {
    print("Imported");
  }
  import();
}
```

- Is this supposed to work?
- Is the language sufficiently stable that using this will continue to work?
- What is special about *import* versus say *class*, which does not work and what other keywords/may be are fair game?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, this is supposed to work. And I think that yes, you can be reasonably sure that this will continue to work. To explain, let's take a look at the language specification.

Section 16.1.1 (Reserved words) explains that *a reserved word may not be used as an identifier; it is a compile-time error if a reserved word is used where an identifier is expected.* Here is the list of reserved words: `assert`, `break`, `case`, `catch`, `class`, `const`, `continue`, `default`, `do`, `else`,
`enum`, `extends`, `false`, `final`, `finally`, `for`, `if`, `in`, `is`, `new`, `null`, `rethrow`, `return`, `super`, `switch`, `this`, `throw`, `true`, `try`, `var`, `void`, `while`, `with`. Note that `import` isn't mentioned here.

Then, sections 12.30 (Identifier Reference) explains that there is a set of *built-in identifiers* which looks like this: `abstract`, `as`, `dynamic`, `export`, `external`, `factory`, `get`, `implements`, `import`, `library`, `operator`, `part`, `set`, `static`, `typedef`. And *it is a compile-time error if a built-in identifier is
used as the declared name of a class, type parameter or type alias.* Note that `import` falls into this group -- so you can't use it as a type, but you can use it elsewhere (like in your case, as a function name).

And a non-normative part of the section 12.30 explains the difference: *Built-in identifiers are identifiers that are used as keywords in Dart, but are not reserved words in Javascript*.

Just to note, in this answer, I quoted the PDF form of the Dart Language Specification version 0.30.

Comment: Ladicek your a dart spec master!